# SPSolution Pages: Where are they found?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am currently training on sharepoint and have few weeks experice with regards to development in sharepoint. My current task involves deploying a .wsp solution on a server farm, and did that using the powershell through the Add-SPSolution, Install-SPSolution, and did that successfully. The problem I am encountering is that in the spsolution I had a webpage named  TestPage.aspx, I cant find where the page is residing such that I can access it. there a specific place where the page resides or any command which I can use?

Comment: Have you tried C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS (`http://site/subsite/_layouts/TestPage.aspx`)?

Comment: I tried it now but it returns an error stating "An Unexpected error has occurred"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio usually creates a folder for application pages, so you may try:

```
http://server/site/_layouts/foldername/TestPage.aspx
```

where **foldername** is the name of your project/solution.

If you get "The resource cannot be found" - HTML 404 error, the site is not there.

Otherwise, even if it says "An Unexpected error has occurred" it does not mean the site is not there. 

The site may exist, but has some errors. In that case the best way would be to check Windows Event Viewer and logs.

Comment: Why didn't you suggest an improvement to my answer instead of providing an answer that is pretty much the same as mine?

Comment: Author never said he created the wsp himself. Therefore I didn’t feel your answer was relevant, the only important part was line _7. access the page in /_layouts/foldernamed/test.aspx_ and the foldernamed part could be easily overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just add an aspx file and deploy on sharepoint.

Maybe what you are after is how to deploy an application page, an application page sits at the application level, so every site collection will be able to access it.

How to deploy an application page:

To add an application page do the following:

1. create a new empty sharepoint project
2. add "Sharepoint "Layouts" Mapped Folder to the project
3. in layouts folder create a folder (usually the name of the project)
4. add an application page to that folder.
5. that application uses sharepoint masterpage, put some content in.
6. Deploy using visual studio or compile and deploy the wsp using the method above
7. access the page in /_layouts/foldernamed/test.aspx*

If you are looking only to add some content to a sharepoint page, then I suggest you use a visual web control. it is basically a user control wrapped in a webpart. After deployed you can add it to a webpart page that you can create using the Sharepoint UI.